# Is it appropriate to use my company laptop for leisure activities?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, technology

My company-issued laptop is quite nice. It's faster and more portable than my personal laptop. I frequently bring it home so that I can check emails and monitor tests I have running

Sometimes I find myself using it at home for leisure activities like watching Netflix or browsing the web (not during work hours, of course!).

Assuming I don't do anything blatantly stupid (downloading porn, installing sketchy software, etc.), is there anything unethical or unprofessional about using my work laptop in this way?

Comment: Is this during work hours? What is your policy regarding laptop use when bringing it home?

Comment: Just use your discretion. Keep in mind that many orgs maintain databases on all URL's you hit with your browser as well as all downloads and connections you make over a network. It is not possible to say how much this applies when you're not on the company network (or connected via VPN). Generally speaking, people can get away with "a lot". Computer misuse is often used as a way of nailing people who are already being targeted for termination for more nebulous reasons.

Comment: A simple possibility is to boot your own *operating system*  from a *live DVD* or an *USB device*. This way you do both: protect your privacy against your company and protect your working environment installed on the hardware against attacks from the internet during your "private" sessions...

Answer (score 13):

**Check your company policy.** I've worked at companies that allow personal use of company laptops, but only to a certain extent. There should be a long list of things you obviously don't do (porn, torrenting, mining Bitcoins) and naturally you need to be extra cautious so that you don't catch a virus or get hacked. But whether or not personal use is outright banned is going to depend on your employer. Ask your manager.

Answer (score 4):

Check and go with the company policy. Usually, companies want you to have a laptop so you can work/take care of company issues on non-company time. As a trade-off, they don't care if you use their stuff on your time for personal reasons.

My company reimburses people for their personal cell phones because they may occasionally want to call employees on it during off hours. It's a compromise that is agreed upon by both parties.

Be open, honest and upfront.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer **NO!**

Longer answer **HELL NO**

It is unethical because a work computer is for work sanctioned activities.  Unless you get permission, the answer is always **NO**.  Even if you did have permission from management, understand that every last keystroke is being monitored.

You may not be doing anything **blatantly** stupid, but you may be doing something that might get you in trouble nonetheless.  Open an email from someone and it contains a Trojan, you just infected the network.

Someone hacks through your home network and gets into your computer, guess who is on the unemployment line.

NO, NO, NO, NO, **NO!**

It is unethical because you are putting your company at risk.  You may even get fired over it.  DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: What year is this?

Comment: @JeffO 2017 ethics don't change every year

Comment: @Neuromancer - I guess I should have asked what decade is this?

Comment: While I expect that some employers do targeted monitoring of "every last keystroke" that is not anywhere near the norm, and it is needlessly alarmist to suggest that is happening to the OP. Instead of creating F.U.D. why not share something more substantive?

Comment: I find this answer surprising because most places I've worked people openly do these kind of activities (playing videos in YouTube, or streaming music, or doing some personal browsing) even while they're at the office.